# incomplete attachment using GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY with depth component

Tags: arrays, opengl, textures, fbo, shadow-mapping

I'm trying to use opengl texture arrays for storing a lot of shadow maps.
Unfortunately, I always get an "incomplete attachment" error on checking the framebuffer.
I tried to set up my texture array like in nvidia's cascaded shadow mapping example (see  [Cascaded Shadow Mapping example by NVIDIA](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10.5/opengl/samples.html)).

So here's some code:

1. creating the texture:

   ```
   glGenTextures(1, &shadowMapArray_);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, shadowMapArray_);
   //maxArrayDepth_ = GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS
   glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, size_, size_, maxArrayDepth_, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LESS);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);
   ```
2. create FBO:

   ```
   glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo_);
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_);
   glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
   ```
3. draw shadow map into layer:

   ```
   glUseProgram(programID_);
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_);
   glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, shadowMapArray_, 0, currArraySize_);
   GLView::checkGLFramebuffer("ShadowMapGenerator::createShadowMap()"); //here i get the incomplete attachment
   [...]
   currArraySize_++;
   ```

System specs:

Debian Squeeze 64bit with Nvidia driver 304.60 and a GTX 560 Ti.
The old driver version is due to a shader compiler bug in the newer versions.

Comment: "`maxArrayDepth_ = GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS`" Do you mean that literally (as in copying the enumerator value) or figuratively (using `glGetIntegerv` with that enumerator and storing it in `maxArrayDepth`)?

Comment: figuratively: glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS, (GLint*)(&maxArrayDepth_));

Comment: Still no answer after two years? Awesome I must be lucky...

Comment: And five years later, here we are, still confused.